# Angularjs undefined error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I have following html

```
 <tbody ng-repeat="c in forms">
        <tr>
            <td> <input type="text" ng-model=c.name /> </td> 
           <td>  <input type="text" ng-model=c.ac />  </td>                         
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="a in c.te">

             <td> <input type="text" ng-model=a.name /> </td> 
             <td>  <input type="text" ng-model=b.ac /></td>                                                                       
         </tr>
  </tbody>
    <button ng-click="add(c)">Add</button>
    <button ng-click="submit(c)">Crate account</button>
```

In my controller

```
 $scope.forms = [{
      "name" : "form1", "ac": 251
    }, {
       "name": "form2", "ac": 252
    }, {
       "name": "form3", "ac": 253
    }];


    $scope.addRows = function (c) {
        alert(form);
        if (typeof c.te == 'undefined') {
            c.te = [];
        }
        alert("pushing");
        c.te.push({ name: '', ac: ''});      
    };
```

I keep getting error at if (typeof c.te=='undefined') saying

```
Error: c is undefined
```

Please let me know what is wrong here. The if statement is supposed to check if it is undefined, but it doest work Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c` is undefined (and not an Object) reading the `te` property throws an error.

Because when checking `typeof c.te === 'undefined'` javascript will first read the property `te` from `c` before performing the `typeof`.

```
if (typeof c === 'undefined') {
   c = {};
}
if (typeof c.te === 'undefined') {
   c.te = [];
}
```

If you know both `c` and `c.te` should be truthy you can write:

```
c = c || {};
c.te = c.te || [];
```

Answer (score 2):

You get the error because the `button` tags are outside the `ng-repeat` directive.

```
<tbody ng-repeat="c in forms">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model=c.name />
        </td> 
        <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model=c.ac />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="a in c.te">
        <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model=a.name />
        </td> 
        <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model=b.ac />
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>

<button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
<button ng-click="submit()">Crate account</button>
```

Your controller code is also weird - you want to add a new record but you seem to be accepting a parameter?

EDIT: If it isn't obvious already, since the button is outside the `ng-repeat` directive, the `c` argument is no longer available for use with the button tag. Hence, when the scope function is called, the parameter is `undefined` and thus the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (typeof c.te == 'undefined') {
        c.te = [];
    }
```

Here you are trying to check if `c.te` is undefined. first you need to check if c is undefined or not. and that's what the error says.